# how to debug without visual studio IDE

Tags: .net, debugging

how to debug a exe without having visual studio IDE

Comment: The one included in Visual Studio obviously isn't the only debugger in the world. But you'll have to be more specific before anyone can recommend one: What language and compiler was used, what OS, other requirements, etc.

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. We could debug something by running several inputs on it. Are you looking for concepts like equivalence partitioning

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using another debugger like [WinDbg](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/installx86.mspx#b) for example. Have a look [here](http://mtaulty.com/communityserver/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2004/08/03/4656.aspx) and [here](http://mtaulty.com/communityserver/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2004/08/03/4671.aspx) (or google around) for an introduction.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Debugger is built into Windows try that. I used to use a decompiler to work out what was happening sometimes, these are usually commercial products, but free ones are out there =]

Answer (score 1):

If you are debugging a managed exe check out mdbg http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2005/02/04/367506.aspx